# SKLabelNode set fontSize according to length of text

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, sklabelnode

Is it posible to set fontSize on SKLabelNode to some dynamic value so that it is max allowed value so that whole text can be shown.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever the label is updated just call a method say `:adjustLabel`. In that

```
- (void)adjustLabel{
    label.text = //Your Text;
    label.fontSize = //Your fontSize; 
    label.position = // Your position;
    // whatever attributes of the label you want to change, add them here.
}
```